# Flash app receiving mouse events without focus

Tags: javascript, flash, jquery-plugins, mouseevent

Just wanted to ask is it possible for a flash app to capture mouse and keyboard events when it loses focus. I've tried putting it in a div container through SWFObject library and than used jquery forward mouse events plugin, but without success. My idea was to capture mouse events (click event) on the body and then transfer it to the flash app. Anybody has some suggestions or knows about a workaround? I haven't tried anything considering the key events. i run a flash games website and i think it will be a cool functionality to add.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you **should** be able to capture any mouse event on the page and pass it along to an swf via ExternalInterface. If not the body element (which does seem like it should work), then some other containing element that expands outside the flash object.

I guess my answer is that your direction should work. It would be my route, anyway. I can't think of any reasons that it wouldn't work...

How are you adding listeners to your page elements?

Answer (score 0):

There are some build-in features that can help you achieve what you want to do:

1) Stage object will fire Event.ACTIVATE and Event.DEACTIVATE events when you click in the flash movie / click outside of the flash movie to give / take away focus.  See [this link for a tutorial](http://blog.tudwaythecore.com/2009/05/detecting_focus/).

2) Stage object will fire an [Event.MOUSE_LEAVE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#event%3amouseLeave) event when mouse cursor leaves the stage area